# Haskell: Ambiguous type variable `b0' arising from a use of `print' prevents the constraint `(Show b0)' from being solved

Tags: haskell

I'm currently trying to implement linked lists in Haskell. So far everything works, including functions for working with these linked lists, but my issue is in the `Show` instance. My code:

```
data LinkedList a = EmptyList | Node a (LinkedList a)

instance (Show a) => Show (LinkedList a) where
    show EmptyList = "{ }"
    show l = "{ " ++ showLL l ++ " }"
        where
            showLL (Node x EmptyList) = show x
            showLL (Node x l) = show x ++ " -> " ++ showLL l
```

If I remove the `(Show a)` constraint, Haskell freaks out because there's no guarantee that `a` is showable. But when I try `print EmptyList`, the constraint cannot be solved since `EmptyList` doesn't have a type `a` which is or isn't showable.
Trying to declare two instances, one with the constraint and one without, gives me the duplicate instance declaration error. Trying to declare it as an instance of `LinkedList` instead of `(LinkedList a)` also gives me an error since it expects an argument to be passed to `LinkedList` (i.e. `a`).

Here is the weirdest part: declaring an instance for `Functor` prevents the error from showing up:

```
instance Functor LinkedList where
    fmap _ EmptyList = EmptyList
    fmap f (Node x l) = Node (f x) (fmap f l)
```

Note that `fmap _ EmptyList = EmptyList`, meaning that regardless of what function I want to map onto an `EmptyList` the result will just be an `EmptyList`.
The part that is confusing to me:

```
print $ EmptyList           -- error
print $ fmap id EmptyList   -- error
print $ fmap (*2) EmptyList -- no error! output is "{ }" as expected
```

So how can I print both a list that is empty and one that is not? And why on Earth does mapping any function that isn't `id` (or anything equivalent like `\x -> x`) not give the same error? Does the `fmap` function somehow return an `EmptyList` that isn't the same as the regular `EmptyList`?

Thanks!

(For the record, I'm using GHCi v8.6.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what the `a` of your `LinkedList` should be when you use `EmptyList`. For `fmap (*2)` that is not a problem since then the type constraints will determine that `a` has to be a `Num` type and this will default to `Integer`, but without such type hint, `a` can be anything.

You can give it a typhint, for example:

```
print (EmptyList :: LinkedList Int)
```

This then produces the expected:

```
Prelude> print (EmptyList :: LinkedList Int)
{ }
```

This might be important, since printing an `EmptyList :: LinkedList Int` might be different from printing `EmptyList :: LinkedList Char` for example.